# Comparing list using for loop and list comprehension

Tags: python, list, scope, list-comprehension

I have a text file where I input specific 6digit code to check if they are in the main text file.

Text files look as below:

```
'MAIN.txt'
4d5x1x  spongebob
2c4b66  bonk
svx123  patrick

'input.txt'
2c4b66
```

In order to find if values 'input.txt' are in 'MAIN.txt' I used following code:

```
list1 = list()
list2 = list()

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    _input = [value[:6] for value in f]

with open('MAIN.txt') as ff:
    for line in ff:

        # for loop
        for x in _input:
            if x == line[:6]:
               list1.append(x)

        # list comprehension
        list2 = [k for k in _input if k == line[:6]]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
list1  - ['2c4b66']
list2  - []
_input  - ['2c4b66']
```

Why is list comprehension not capturing any value?

Comment: Because `list2` value is getting replaced at each iteration inside the outer `for` loop. Print `list1`  and `list2` after the comprehension inside the outer `for` loop, you will know what's going on.

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'list1' is not defined`

Comment: Separately, `k` and `line` are already strings. You don't have to do `str(k)` and `str(line[:6])`

Comment: Is it always one 6-char word in input.txt file?

Comment: initialization inserted. removed str() 
@Hamzawi yes always 6 char

Comment: do you mind if I give you an optimized solution for your problem?

Comment: @Hamzawi I think quamrana's answer seems enough. appreciate your effort though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have meant to write this code:

```py
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    _input = [value[:6] for value in f]

list1 = []
list2 = []
with open('MAIN.txt') as ff:
    for line in ff:

        # for loop
        for x in _input:
            if str(x) == str(line[:6]):
               list1.append(x)

        # list comprehension
        list2.append([k for k in _input if k == line[:6]])

print(list1)
print(list2)
print(_input)
```

Here I set both `list1` and `list2` to empty lists and call `.append()` at appropriate times in the loops.

Output:

```
['2c4b66']
[[], ['2c4b66'], []]
['2c4b66']
```

This shows how `list2` captures the fact that `2c4b66` matches only the second line of `MAIN.txt`

Comment: I think `extend` would have been better than `append`, that way, `list1` and `list2` will be identical.

Comment: Thank you! I thought list comprehension appended by itself. guess I totally misunderstood how it works. @ThePyGuy `extend` seems perfect! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the control structure: there is a different value of `list2` for each `line in ff`, but a global `list1` . So `list1` collects all of the lines that match an input, but over the course of the program, `list2` is:

```
[]
['2c4b66']
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: you could try this as well:

```
 import numpy as np

main_lines =open("MAIN.txt").read().splitlines()
input_lines =open("input.txt").read().splitlines()

words = [i.split() for i in main_lines ]
main_words = np.concatenate(words)

words = [i.split() for i in input_lines ]
input_words = np.concatenate(words)

found_words = [word for word in input_words if word in main_words]
```